# How do I load a file that I bundled with the install of my C# program?

Tags: c#, installation, streamreader, readfile

I need to do something like this:

```
    StreamReader reader = 
new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Program Files\The Awesome Program That I Made\awesomeloadablefile.ldf");
```

Except I don't know where the user has installed the program.  How is my program supposed to know where the installed files are?

I am a noob, in case you hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) to get the path on disk of your executable, [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) to get the directory it's in, and then [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to combine the directory name with your file name in that directory.  So:

```
StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), 
    "awesomeloadablefile.ldf"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

Answer (score 0):

Something like `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "awesomeloadablefile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the directory structure relative to your executable, you can use `Application.StartupPath`:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "awesomeloadablefile.ldf");
StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a path to the exe directory. I'm assuming that's where you decided to put the file. Otherwise you can specify a had location for it in the installer. Are you using the Visual Studio installer?

```
Application.StartupPath
```